# send data from jsp form to database in spring (without using servlets)

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, servlets

i have a form where i want the user to fill it in and then hit a submit button which will send the data to a database.

this is the form:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addQuestion" >

   <input type="text" name="questionId" />Enter Id<br>
   <input type="text" name="theQuestion" />Enter Q <br>
   <input type="text" name="category" />Enter Category<br>
   <input type="text" name="correctAnswer" />Enter correct answer<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Next"  >

</form:form>
```

and addQuestion should be called in this webcontroller.java class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addQuestion(Model model, @RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value="questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category, @RequestParam(value="correctAnswer", required = true)   String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
        ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
        viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);

        return new ModelAndView("qFour", "question", new Question());
    }
```

and then viewController should be invoked which connects to the DAO to submit data to the database. however, at the moment, when submit is clicked it just refreshes the page or rather just deletes all the data entered into the input boxes

Comment: Tehcnically, you're using `DispatchServlet` behind the scenes, which orchestrates all the calls from your view and translate it to your model (in this case, the `WebController` class).

Answer (score 0):

Look up `@ModelAttribute` in Spring and on `Spring Forms` tags and annotations. The following will need just a bit of work but it should point you in the right direction.

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="question" action="addQuestion" >

<form:input path="questionId" />Enter Id<br>
<form:input path="theQuestion" />Enter Q <br>
<form:input path="category" />Enter Category<br>
<form:input path="correctAnswer" />Enter correct answer<br>
<form:button type="submit">Next</form:button>

</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addQuestion", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addQuestion(@ModelAttribute Question question) {

@ModelAttribute("question")
public Question createQuestion() {
   return new Question();
}
```

Comment: doesn't like your form as says it's unbalanced...might need to do with setting the prefix maybe.

Comment: `<form:button type="submit">Next</form:button>`

Comment: Copy and pasting code without knowing what it does is a terrible way to put a program together. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html